PYTHON: Trying to divide elements alternately from a list to two already existing sublists in another list. No imports please
For context, I have a list of "players" ready. Let's say players = ['steve','gary','simon','kevin'].
And I also have a list with two sublists with a "leader" in each of them: groups = [['leader1'],['leader2']]
Now, I need to distribute the players to their leaders alternately:
groups = [['leader1','steve','simon'],['leader2','gary','kevin']]
I've been stumped on this task for quite some time and would greatly appreciate a little help.
And also, no imports please, thanks!
I've already tried so many different ways of solving this, but to no avail.
The following is one of the attempts I was really hopeful about:
for i in range(len(players))
   for j in range(len(groups))
      groups[j].append(players[i])

In retrospect, of course this wouldn't work but I was just really tired (and still am :D).

Curious, would a dictionary work as well? With the keys being the leaders, and values being those players??

Note: using slicing, players[::2] = ['steve', 'simon']

Your groups exist at indices 0 and 1. A trick for alternating between the two indices is to subtract each index from 1 to get the other.
i = 0
for p in players:
  groups[i].append(p)
  i = 1 - i  # 1 - 0 == 1, 1 - 1 = 0


Using an import from the standard library (there's little reason to avoid it),
from itertools import cycle

for player, team in zip(players, cycle(groups)):
    team.append(player)

Iterating over cycle(groups) just iterates over the contents repeatedly for as long as zip needs value. team is alternate set to groups[0], groups[1], groups[0], groups[1], etc, for as long as there is an available player for zip to pair with a group.

Using your current approach as a starting point, you don't need a nested loop.  The index to be used in groups can be determined by a modulo operation on i.  For example:
for i in range(len(players)):
    groups[i % len(groups)].append(players[i])

So player 0 goes to group 0, player 1 to group 1, player 2 to group 0, etc.

Alternatively, you can slice lists.  For example:
for i in range(len(groups)):
    groups[i].extend(players[i::len(groups)])

This should, for each group, slice the players into a list which starts at i and includes another player every len(groups) number of indices.  So players 0 and 2 are in group 0, 1 and 3 are in group 1, etc.

As a general word of advice, you might find dictionaries which contain lists to be an easier data structure to use.  These "groups" appear to have two distinct properties, a single "leader" value and a list of "player" values.  Keeping them separate is probably best.
